# Vue3 Using same component/object in both parts of v-if / else

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I want to one have one instance of a component that is displayed in both parts of a v-if / v-else construct, simplified example:

```html
<div v-if="xyz">
   <CompA/>
</div>
<div v-else>
   <CompA/>
</div>
```

But I want to only have one instance of CompA and reuse it in the two locations, so it's like declared outside and somehow injected depending on which part is visible. Is this possible?

Comment: Consider explaining your case, it's likely something different than you showed, this could be XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is what `key` is for, it allows to designate that element subtree is the same when builtin directives are used and prevents `CompA` from being unmounted between renders:

```
<div v-if="xyz" key="a">
   <CompA/>
</div>
<div v-else key="a">
   <CompA/>
</div>
```

But this won't work as intended if the subtrees are different, which is likely the case here, otherwise this example could be reduced to:

```
<div>
   <CompA/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that .. though yeah it won't help here as the subtrees will be different. I was trying to keep the example as simple as possible to avoid alternatives which wouldn't help in my actual use case.

Comment: Consider explaining your case then. Generally you just move component state to parent component or global store, so you don't worry about it being remounted

Comment: yeah I know it can easily be done with multiple instances of the same component .. it just feels a bit ugly to me and was hoping a way around this. 10 years ago without vue or other frameworks, would manually move the object into the right place in dom in these situations.

Comment: From framework perspective, it's attaching a child to a different parent that is ugly. Still can be done in exotic cases but not when it's needed to preserve child state. That you have to do this may indicate that components were separated the wrong way. Any way, a proper answer requires to explain the whole case, it cannot be answered in general

Comment: It's not about state, just seems a 'waste' to have multiple instances of the same thing. I think what I want can probably be done with Teleport https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/teleport.html#basic-usage  but I agree with your statement in first sentence of last comment, so it's probably not a good idea and best to have 2 instances.

Comment: Yes, doable with a teleport, didn't mention it because it may provide more overhead and problems than it's worth in a situation like this one, like cryptic errors due to more complex comp life cycles